# Is there any algorithm to find the solution of a system of 2 linear and 1 algebraic equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations

I have a system such as:

$$\begin{aligned}
a_1+b_1t&=u\\
a_2+b_2t&=v\\
a_3+b_3t&=f(u,v)\;
\end{aligned}$$

Where `a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3` are known constants, `t, u, v` are real variables and `f(u,v)` is an algebraic function. Is there any known algorithm to solve that system for `t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your notations, just replacing,  you then have $$a_3+b_3t=f(a_1+b_1t,a_2+b_2t)=\Phi(t)$$ which makes one (implicit) equation in $t$. The solutions for $t$ would probably require some iterative numerical schemes such as Newton or other root-finders.

You may visualize the problem as the intersection of a straight line $y=a_3+b_3t$ and a curve $y=\Phi(t)$.